# CentOS 7.4.1708: ERROR: x265 not found using pkg-config

Tags: ffmpeg, centos7, pkg-config, libx265

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg with Nvidia support following the guides on https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos and https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg. I've ended up with the following command:

`PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --enable-pthreads --disable-w32threads --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build"   --pkg-config-flags="--static"   --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include"   --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64"   --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm'   --bindir="$HOME/bin"   --enable-gpl   --enable-libfdk_aac   --enable-libfreetype   --enable-libmp3lame   --enable-libopus   --enable-libvorbis   --enable-libvpx   --enable-libx264  --enable-libx265    --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp`

I'm getting the wonderful error

> ERROR: x265 not found using pkg-config

looking in `ffbuild/config.log` reveals the following error:

```
gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -I/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -std=c11 -fomit-frame-pointer -pthread -I/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include/opus -I/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include/opus -I/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include -I/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include -I/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include -I/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include -I/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include -I/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include -I/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include -I/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include -L/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/lib -c -o /tmp/ffconf.MfrVBc4k/test.o /tmp/ffconf.MfrVBc4k/test.c
In file included from /tmp/ffconf.MfrVBc4k/test.c:1:0:
/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include/x265.h:1753:40: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
 FILE* x265_csvlog_open(const x265_param& param);
                                        ^
/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include/x265.h:1757:40: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
 void x265_csvlog_frame(const x265_param& param, const x265_picture& pic);
                                        ^
/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include/x265.h:1762:64: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
 void x265_csvlog_encode(x265_encoder *encoder, const x265_stats& stats, int argc, char** argv);
                                                                ^
/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include/x265.h:1766:36: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
 void x265_dither_image(x265_picture& pic, int picWidth, int picHeight, int16_t *errorBuf, int bitDepth);
                                    ^
/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include/x265.h:1815:50: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
     FILE*         (*csvlog_open)(const x265_param&);
                                                  ^
/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include/x265.h:1816:51: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
     void          (*csvlog_frame)(const x265_param&, const x265_picture&);
                                                   ^
/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include/x265.h:1817:67: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
     void          (*csvlog_encode)(x265_encoder*, const x265_stats&, int, char**);
                                                                   ^
/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include/x265.h:1818:47: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
     void          (*dither_image)(x265_picture&, int, int, int16_t*, int);
                                               ^
/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build/include/x265.h:1820:1: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union [enabled by default]
 } x265_api;
 ^
```

gcc version is gcc-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64

As per a question below: Yes - x265 is installed as per https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos and yes pkg-config is finding it. The compilation error makes me think that I'm missing a flag to the --pkg-config-flags optnion, but I can't find one that works.

Does anyone know what I should be passing to pkg-config to get it to enable x265?

Comment: Either install the x265 codec library or don't specify that you want to use. This obviously has nothing to do with CUDA so I have removed the tag. In fact I really don't see where this question (such as it is, did you even really ask a question?) is particularly on-topic for [SO] at all.

Comment: x265 is installed - as per the first guide that I was following. You'll notice that the error message is a syntax problem of some sorts, not that x265.h couldn't be found. I'll revise this to make the question a bit more obvious :-)

Comment: What does your x265.pc say?

Comment: Here's the contents of x265.pc

prefix=/home/agilbert/ffmpeg_build
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include
 
Name: x265
Description: H.265/HEVC video encoder
Version: 2.5
Libs: -L${libdir} -lx265
Libs.private: -lstdc++ -lm -lrt -ldl
Cflags: -I${includedir}

Comment: I can reproduce the same error by running the same gcc command, but if I use g++ instead of gcc, then it compile correctly. No I have to figure out how to make either configure or pkg-config use g++ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this helps anyone else, I figured out in the end that I didn't need to supply the option `--enable-libx265` when you also specify `--enable-nvenc`.

I still don't know what the compilation error was, but with `--enable-nvenc` you can encode in H.265 with nVidia-based GPU acceleration.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent _so much time_ fighting with this. Adding `--enable-nvenc` fixed my issues even though ffmpeg says it's an invalid option.